# Getting {byte[0]} as output while convert stream to Byte

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, stream

Hi I want to convert Stream to Byte and for this I am using the below code for converting.

```
  void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {

            var imageSrc = new BitmapImage();
            imageSrc.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            imgUploadedInsurance.Source = imageSrc;               
            _BitmapImage.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            image = Converter.StreamToByte(e.ChosenPhoto);
        }
    }
```

Below method is used for converting which is returning 0 byte

```
  public static byte[] StreamToByte(Stream input)
    {
        //byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

               // input.CopyTo(ms);


            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You souldn't return `ms.ToArray()`, but `buffer`. Here's my version of the method that will work:

```cs
public static byte[] StreamToByte(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];
    input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return buffer;
}
```